# In MS-Word, Can I write text in different color from that of the style of the paragraph?

Tags: microsoft-word, colors

I want to write a MS word document which analyzes an assembly code.
For that, firt I copied the assembly code in MS-word in default black color. Now I want to add my comments in the code with different color (like red). Of course I can add comment, select the comment, and change the comment color to red. But this is cumbersome. I want to just add the comments and want it to have red color. Can I do it? (if there's an option setting the font color temporarily red.. In powerpoint we can set the color of the pen regardless of where we write or draw..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as demonstrated in the picture: Press the button with the A and a red bar beneath.

[image: picture]

Hope it worked!
Best regards, norway-yv

Comment: By the way: I am Norwegian and utilise Norwegian MS Word for penmanship. Hence, the illustrations may not look precisely like your Word. Furthermore, I have added a unique tab at the top. As a consequence of this, the Home (Hjem) and Insert (Sett inn) tabs are further to the right than without my personal tab.

Comment: yap! that looks the best way. clicking the color before I write. :) thanks!

Comment: No problem, I am happy to help. Thanks for the accept by the way!

Answer (score 1):

### Use a Character Style instead of direct formatting. You'll be glad you did.

You can create and then apply a custom character style that has the color you want. This gives you much more power over your text than does directly applying the color. *Using direct formatting instead of styles is shooting yourself in the foot!*

- Here is a link to [my writing on the importance of Styles in Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Overview).
- Here is a link to [Word MVP Shauna Kelly's page on Styles](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/styles/stylesms.html).